# How to send the output of the FOR loop as the input to itself in Scala?

Tags: scala, append, arraybuffer

Add elements to the array buffer such that the element to be added is the product of the previous two elements of the input array buffer. The elements in the output array buffer should not exceed 10000.

Input ArrayBuffer:- ArrayBuffer(2, 3)
Expected Output ArrayBuffer:- ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 6, 18, 108, 1944)
Actual Output ArrayBuffer:- ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 6, 18)

```
def main(args: ArrayBuffer[Int]): Unit = {
    for(k <- 1 to args.length if(args(k) < 10000)){
      args += args(k)*args(k-1)
    }
    println(args)
  }
```

Here I took *args* from main function as input to the for block. Then it calculates and appends the result to *args* only upto the previous length of the input say (2, 3) that is 2. But the length should increase as the elements keep appending to the arraybuffer. Say after the 1st iteration args will be (2, 3, 6, 18). Now this should be fed as input to the FOR block and it should continue till last value reaches closest min value to 10000.

If I find solution for this, I will update here. Until then, please help me solving this

Comment: "Sending an output as an input to itself" sounds like a recursion.

Comment: Read about structural recursion for `List`. Also there are functions `List.iterate(start, len)(f)`, `List.unfold(init)(f)`, `list.foldRight(init)((a, acc) => ...)`, `list.foldLeft(init)((acc, a) => ...)`, `list.fold(init)((a, a1) => ...)`, `list.reduce((a, a1) => ...)`, `list.reduceLeft((acc, a) => ...)`,  `list.reduceRight((a, acc) => ...)` hiding recursion inside them.

Comment: By the way, there is function `ArrayBuffer.unfold(...)` too

Answer (score 1):

Following is an adder version,

```
@tailrec
def adder(args: List[BigDecimal], size: Int = args.length): List[BigDecimal] = {
  args.reverse match {
    case first :: second :: rest if size < 10000 => adder(((first + second) :: first :: second :: rest).reverse, size + 1)
    case _ => args
  }
}
```

But this won't work for multiplication as even a simple input of `List(1,2)` would crash with `ArithmeticException: Overflow` at size 48.

**EDIT**

I had misunderstood the OP as the total number of elements to be less than 10000.

updated version:

```
@tailrec
def multiplier(args: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  args.reverse match {
    case first :: second :: rest if first * second < 10000 => multiplier(((first * second) :: first :: second :: rest).reverse)
    case _ => args
  }
}
```

or

```
def multiplier(args: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  @tailrec
  def generate(args: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    args match {
      case first :: second :: rest if first * second < 10000 => generate((first * second) :: first :: second :: rest)
      case _ => args
    }
  }
  generate(args.reverse).reverse
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An implementation in FP style would be

```
2 :: 3 :: List.unfold((2, 3)) { case (x, y) =>
  val p = x * y
  Option.when(p < 10000)((p, (y, p)))
}
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/library/scala/collection/Factory.scala#L114-L124

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. As I like to solve any question in a simple and easy way, I found this one too in same manner. I've replaced *for loop* with a *while loop* and made tiny changes like below

```
while(args(i)*args(i-1) < 10000){
  args += args(i)*args(i-1)
  i += 1
}
```

Now I got the expected Output as I mentioned in my question above
See you all when my next doubt pops up...